# Call a function in class members (C++)

Tags: c++, class, scope, friend, access-control

#### Z.h

```
struct Z {
    Z();
    ~Z();
    void DoSomethingNasty();
}
```

#### X.h

```
struct X {
    X();
    ~X();
    void FunctionThatCallsNastyFunctions();
}
```

#### MainClass.h

```
#include "Z.h"
#include "X.h"

struct MainClass {
    MainClass();
    ~MainClass();
  private:
    Z _z;
    X _x;
}
```

#### X.cpp

```
X::FunctionThatCallsNastyFunctions() {
  //How can I do this? The compiler gives me error.
  _z.DoSomethingNasty();
}
```

What should i do in order to call `DoSomethingNasty()` function from `_z` object?

Comment: Sharing the error message would help.

Comment: Your code has a typo _z.DoeSomethingNasty(); does _z.DoSomethingNasty(); give the error

Comment: I really doubt you need those destructors. (And for the sake of example, the constructors.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The compiler is giving you an error because `_z` doesn't exist within the `X` class; it exists within the `MainClass` class. If you want to call a method on a `Z` object from `X`, you either need to give `X` its own `Z` object or you have to pass one to it as a parameter. Which of these is appropriate depends on what you're trying to do.

I think your confusion may be this: You think that because `MainClass` has both a `X` member and a `Z` member, they should be able to access each other. That's not how it works. `MainClass` can access both of them, but the `_x` and `_z` objects, within their member functions, have no idea about anything outside their own class.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have to find another solution then.

Comment: You could try static methods, and you can access them with Z::DoesSomethingNasty(). You would need to pre-declare Class Z in your X file though. Or you would have to take a z object as a parameter to FuncitonThatCallsNastyFunctions.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the compiler error but from the sample I'm guessing the compiler error is because you only declared the DoSomethingNasty function but did not define it.  This would result in an error at link time.

Try adding the following code to your .cpp file

```
void Z::DoSomethingNasty() {
  // Code here
}
```

Additionally as @Tyler pointed out, the X class does not have a member variable named `_z` from which to call the function on.